# Why does this modular function form a sinusoidal wave?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

In playing around on Desmos graphing calculator, I tried reproducing wave-like functions using modular arithmetic. I came upon this equation: $$y = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\bmod(x^2,n)$$
I do not have much experience with modular forms, so I'm not sure how to explain this phenomenon. It should also be noted that increasing the quantity $N$ results in a more clearly defined graph.

Here is its graph with N set to $500$: [graph of above equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Azk.png)

Comment: Where does $x$ lie?

Comment: What is $n$? I can't reproduce the graph by holding it constant or by setting $n=N$.

Comment: @GabrielTurner might be worth noting that if you rescale your equation by replacing $x^2$ with $N x$ and the $N$ outside with $N^2$, the graph appears to approach a limiting curve as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: @S.C., yes, you are correct, I saw this graph in formulating my original, but on a large scale of $N$ when $x^2$ is simply replaced with $x$ from the original.

Comment: Trying with $x$ instead of $x^2$ and there is a clearer pattern of a dampened oscillation. It's sort of a ball bouncing lower and lower every $N$ units.

Comment: By the way, *modular form* and *modular function* already have a meaning in mathematics, and it is very far from what you are using the terms to mean – so, please don't use those terms for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that within each interval the function is a parabola with a peak occurring inside that interval. This is what causes both the increase and decrease as well as the sharp corners at certain points. There might be a simpler way to get this result, but what follows was my thought process.

As I suggested in the comments, let's start by rescaling a bit.

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\mod}{mod}
f_N(x) := \frac 1 {N^2} \sum_{n=1}^N \mod(x \cdot N, n)$$

Then your function is $N \cdot f_N((x/N)^2)$, which means that it's scaled horizontally and vertically by a factor of $N$ and the argument is squared, which has the effect that the horizontal axis is increasingly squished as $x$ increases.

Now $\mod(a, b)$ is the same as $b \cdot \mod(a/b, 1)$, so

$$
f_N(x) = \frac 1 {N^2} \sum_{n = 1}^N n \cdot \mod(x \cdot \frac N n, 1)
$$

Rearranging some of the factors, this is

$$
f_N(x) = \frac 1 {N} \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac n N \cdot \mod(x \cdot \frac N n, 1)
$$

Now this is a Riemann sum with $N$ rectangles with coordinates ranging from $1/N$ to $N/N = 1$. So taking the limit as $N \to \infty$, this tends towards

$$
f(x) := \int_0^1 t \cdot \mod(\frac x t, 1) dt
$$

Making the change of variables $t \to 1/t$, this becomes

$$
f(x) = \int_1^\infty \frac {\mod(x \cdot t, 1)} {t^3} dt
$$

One more change of variables $t \to t/x$ leaves us with

$$
f(x) = x^2 \int_x^\infty \frac {\mod(t, 1)} {t^3} dt
$$

---

It will be helpful to separately analyze this for $x$ within each unit interval $[k, k + 1]$ for integer k since the graph looks different within those intervals. To this end it'll actually be better to use the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ rather than $\mod(x, 1)$. These are closely related, since $x - \lfloor x \rfloor = \mod(x, 1)$. Substituting that into the integral, we get

$$
f(x) = x^2 \int_x^\infty \frac {t - \lfloor t \rfloor} {t^3} dt = x^2 \int_x^\infty \frac t {t^3} dt - x^2 \int_x^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor} {t^3} dt
$$

The first integral is easy and results in

$$
f(x) = x - x^2 \int_x^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor} {t^3} dt
$$

Let's just focus on that integral for a moment. We can start by breaking up $\lfloor t \rfloor$ as $(\lfloor t \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor) + \lfloor x \rfloor$.

$$
\int_x^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor} {t^3} dt = \int_x^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor} {t^3} dt + \int_x^\infty \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor} {t^3} dt
$$

Between $x$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor + 1$, $\lfloor t \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is zero, so the first integral is equal to $\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor + 1}^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor} {t^3} dt$. This integral is locally constant in the sense that if you know that $x$ is in the interval $(k, k + 1)$, the value only depends on $\lfloor x \rfloor = k$, not the particular value of x. This will be important.

The second integral is easy and evaluates to ${\lfloor x \rfloor} / ({2 x^2})$. Substituting this into the expression for $f(x)$, we get

$$
f(x) = x - x^2 \left(\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor + 1}^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor} {t^3} dt + \frac {\lfloor x \rfloor} {2 x^2} \right) = \frac {-\lfloor x \rfloor} 2 + x - \left(\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor + 1}^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor} {t^3} dt \right) x^2
$$

Again, since $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is locally constant, the coefficients here are locally constant, and so this is a parabola on each interval $[k, k + 1]$. The peak of this parabola is at $x_p = 1/(2 \int_{k + 1}^\infty \frac {\lfloor t \rfloor - k} {t^3} dt)$.

This answer is already a bit long, so I'll hold off on rigorously estimating that interval. Suffice to say, if we make the approximation $\lfloor t \rfloor \approx t - 1/2$, we get $x_p \approx k + 1/2$, which is therefore inside the interval $[k, k + 1]$.